# Identifying the individual word lengths in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I am trying to identify the individual word lengths in a pandas dataframe columns:

I know that the len function with list comprehension will result in a list of individual word lengths when done as a standalone code.

```
words = ["alpha","omega","up","down","over","under","purple","red","blue","green"]
[len(i) for i in words]
[5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5]
```

but when I tried to use len function with list comprehension in a pandas dataframe column(see below), I get the sum of the words and not the individual word lengths which is what I need.

```
df['test'] = [len(i) for i in df['words']] #Code: len function within a list comprehension 
[43] #Result the sum of all words in cell rather than individual word length
[5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5] #Result I need the individual word lengths in a list
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["alpha","omega","up","down","over"])
s.str.len()
```

output:

```
0    5
1    5
2    2
3    4
4    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words': ["alpha","omega","up","down","over","under","purple","red","blue","green"]})

df['len'] = [len(w) for w in df['words']]
```

But you can also use [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df['len'] = df['words'].str.len()
```

Output:

```
    words  len
0   alpha    5
1   omega    5
2      up    2
3    down    4
4    over    4
5   under    5
6  purple    6
7     red    3
8    blue    4
9   green    5
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this would be to just create a new column, and then go from there.

`df['word_length'] = df['words'].apply(len)` Take the words column, apply the `len` function, and use that in a new row.

*word_length*

```
0    5
1    5
2    2
3    4
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    3
8    4
9    5
Name: word_length, dtype: int64
```